# HLA - usage of timeAdvanceRequest()

Tags: java, simulation, federation, high-level-architecture

I have HLA simulation in Java using pRTI with two federates. I want to advance time of my simulation. As far I know, following method is used for this purpose:

```
_ambassador.timeAdvanceRequest(time);
```

, where `ambassador` is an RTI ambassador.

My question is what to pass into `time` parameter? I assume it should be the time I want my simulation advance to, but how to get this one?

Comment: I've changed the tag, since the `hla` tag refers to High Level Assembly, not High Level Architecture (simulation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

It is neccessary to use one of LogicalTime interface implementations, for example using TimeFactory:

```
LogicalTime time =  _ambassador.getTimeFactory().makeFinal();
```

calling `timeAdvanceRequest()` will send request to RTI. The, if time was advanced, the timeAdvanceGrant() will be called on federate.

Further info [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15413-s99/www/hla/doc/rti_synopsis/06-Time_Management/Time_Management.html).

Comment: Did this approach work for you? Were you actually seeing timeAdvanceGrant callbacks and, if so, what were those times? I would assume that you'd never get a timeAdvanceGrant because the requested time is bigger than all possible times (I thought makeFinal() is supposed to return the largest possible time value). I know this question and answer are old but I'd be interested to know how you managed this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I think it is supposed to work in HLA 1516-2010. From HLA 1516-2010, the RTI is required to provide two time representations: `HLAinteger64Time` and `HLAfloat64Time` (sections 12.4 and 12.11.2 of the HLA Interface Specification). To access these, you use the `LogicalTimeFactoryFactory`. For example, the following code gets a `HLAfloat64TimeFactory`:

```
HLAfloat64TimeFactory timeFactory = 
     (HLAfloat64TimeFactory)LogicalTimeFactoryFactory.getLogicalTimeFactory("HLAfloat64Time")
```

This `timeFactory` instance can then be used to create `HLAfloat64Time` and `HLAfloat64Interval` instances:

```
HLAfloat64Time t = timeFactory.makeTime(3.0);
HLAfloat64Interval interval = timeFactory.makeInterval(1.0);
```

or, using the interfaces

```
LogicalTime t = timeFactory.makeTime(3.0);
LogicalTimeInterval interval = timeFactory.makeInterval(1.0);
```

Similar code is used for an Integer time factory.